# What does "mvn -P" do?

Tags: maven, command-line, maven-plugin, build-automation

I have been told to use `mvn clean install -P base` at work for a particular task. I am trying to find what it exactly means.

According to https://maven.apache.org/archives/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html , `-P` lists all available plugins; and `-p` is used to specify a project file (assuming pom).

But when I typed `mvn -P` in my command line, I got an error saying:

Unable to parse command line options: Missing argument for option: P

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

What do the `-P` and `-p` stand for, and what are they used for exactly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[A reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) tells us that `-P` specifies which profile Maven is to run under.  Projects can define multiple profiles which may pull in different dependencies, so this is required if you have a project that can do that.

The `-p` flag isn't one I've run into in practice, nor does it really seem to exist in modern versions of Maven.